# How to compute the following 1D general integral as?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Assume we have the 1D general integral as

\begin{equation}
I=\int_m^n \left(\frac{P}{\lambda T r^{\alpha(1-\epsilon)}n^{\alpha\epsilon} + P}\right)^{\theta} \frac{1}{n-m} dr
\end{equation}

with

$m, n, P, \lambda, T, \alpha, \epsilon, \theta$ are constant.

How to derive a general result? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.